# First order BVP with variable integrating factor

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

How can I solve $$\lambda(t)g(t)=g'(t)-rg(t)+\theta h(t),\;g(T)=0.$$ This is a first order ode with integrating factor $e^{-\int (r+\lambda(t))dt}$ but the limits make it a bit tricky.